# C# Webapi Odata return response from another Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following function:

```
        // GET: odata/EmpUtil
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<OriginalDetail> GetEmpUtil()
        {
            var test = db.OriginalDetail

                        .GroupBy(s => new { s.Billable_Project, s.Billable_Activity, s.Time_Date, s.Work_Hours_Per_Week })
                        .Select(x => new AggregateDetail {
                            Billable_Project = x.Key.Billable_Project,
                            Billable_Activity = x.Key.Billable_Activity,
                            Time_Date = x.Key.Time_Date,
                            Daily_Employee_Hours = x.Max(wh => wh.Work_Hours_Per_Week) / 5,
                            Total_Hours = x.Sum(th => th.Total_Hours)
                        });
            return test;
        }
```

As is seen above, I have **OriginalDetail** as Iqueryable, and I want to return **AggregateDetail** object. Also, I want the odata filters and queries to work on **odata/EmpUtil**, that is filters and queries should work on **originalDetail**, hence, i am trying to do this way.

Since test's return type is not of **OriginalDetail**, the groupBy query cannot be returned. How can it be made to work?

I am using webapi2 and odata3.

Comment: At the moment, test will be ```IQueryable<AggregateDetail>```, whereas your function signature is ```IQueryable<OriginalDetail>```, so you are right, that is not going to work. Can you change the function return type to ```IQueryable<AggregateDetail>``` ?

Comment: Doing this will not let odata filters and queries work on OriginalDetail.

Comment: How does one handle custom response with groupby and aggreagate results with odata and client end filters on original model, if it is that complex?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familar with odata, but can you not implement a common interface on ```AggregateDetail``` and ```OriginalDetail``` and use that instead?

Comment: But it looks like the content is different. Can you write your  filters and queries code based on ```AggregateDetail```  instead?  But I think I will have to bow out here, since I don't know too much about odata (off to read up). I hope someone who does, can help you!